# When to rely on garbage collection and when not?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

If I'm going to do this kinda operation many times:

```
  res = mysql_perform_query(conn, "show tables");

  printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL)
      printf("%s\n", row[0]);
```

Do I need to run `mysql_free_result(res);` at the end of each operation or rely on garbage collection mechanism , why?

**UPDATE**

I still don't see clearly how to judge whether some data structure needs to clean up according to existing answer.

Comment: You need to run the cleanup function. C++ doesn't do garbage collection.

Comment: If you're looking for a language with a GC, take a look at Java or C#.

Comment: Can you explain why I don't need to clean up `row` ?

Answer (score 2):

In C++, never. C++ is not garbage-collected. The closest would be [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII), which is basically wrapping stuff that needs cleanup in objects that do said cleanup in their destructor. I can't give further detail since I don't really use C++ all that much.

As an aside: Even in a GC'd language, GC only works well for memory. Explicit cleanup's still needed for stuff like SQL connections, file handles, etc.

Bottom Line: **You always have to clean up once you're done.**
(Unless the documentation says it's not needed)

Comment: Why don't I need to clean up `row` each time then?

Comment: Sorry, bad phrasing on my part. I answered the title, not the question body. I meant "never rely on GC because it's not there". Either clean up every time or cache and reuse the row (if applicable).

Comment: @ollydbg - You should clean up row each time as well but that depends on your implementation, as to in which scope you are declaring row, and if you are reusing the same or not.

Comment: But there is no such an API to clean up `MYSQL_ROW`

Comment: @Als,isn't the `row` in my example different on each loop obviously?

Comment: Well, if there's no API to clean up the row, then it's safe to assume you don't need to clean it up, don't you think? Check the docs, they should say if something needs cleanup.

Comment: Can't we infer whether something needs to clean up by the code itself?

Comment: Just looking at the code will never give you the whole picture. You might miss crucial details.

Comment: *MYSQL_ROW row;* is a variable that is not allocated by malloc(). When the execution flow leaves main(), this resource is going to be destroyed. Each time your loop iterates "row" is overwritten with a new value and no new memory is allocated for it.

Comment: @ollydbg - sorry I am unfamiliar with PHP API's. looks like the API returns you a array "row" and then you can use that array further on.Also, it is not safe to assume that cleanups will be done by an API. The API doccumentation will clearly mention whether it will clear the dynamic allocations or you need to do so.

Comment: The essence of my question is to infer whether to clean up by the function declaration,not according to the doc.

Comment: Then the answer will always be no, you can't infer such a thing.